# Does quantum computing imply LPO?

Tags: logic, quantum-computing

The binary expansion of a given real number can be encoded as an amplitude using the inverse QPE. Together with Amplitude Amplification, I wonder if this could indicate that the (some weakened?) trichotomy of the real numbers is physically effective.

---

I think the crux of the question is that these assumptions that

- "the amplitudes and probabilities in quantum field theory are *fake* complex or real numbers and therefore cannot imply **LPO**"
- "Turing machines can evolve to a pure state that does not-not-stop and is not identical to the any stop state"
- Anti-Markov's principle ...

It is inexplicable in terms of the field equations and which are never observed in experiments.

---

[1] **LPO**: Limited principle of omniscience

[2] QPE: Quantum Phase Estimation

Comment: The standard answer to this sort of question is that it is ignoring error/precision limits that occur in physically real devices. So assumptions like, "the binary expansion of a real number can be encoded as an amplitude," are just false. Only finitely precise neighborhoods of real/complex numbers can be prepared/measured, not single numbers. Even if any particular amplitutde corresponds exactly to a real number, there are limits to how precisely the amplitudes can be prepared, which prevent encoding an exact value. I'm no QC expert, but I imagine this applies to this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. It is known that Turing machines can simulate quantum machines (albeit very inefficiently). If there were a quantum machine that realized LPO then we could simulate it on a Turing machine – but a Turing machine cannot realize LPO, because doing so would give us the Halting Oracle.

Comment: Yes, this is a very common answer, but can there be a more "intuitive" proof? Either "the amplitudes and probabilities in quantum field theory are *fake* complex or real numbers and therefore cannot imply LPO" or "Turing machines can evolve to a pure state that does not-not-stop and is not identical to the initial state" is very strange.

Comment: and by this "reasoning", Markov's Principle appears to be physically effective....

Comment: Fix some errors: initial state -> any stop state

Comment: I find this proof intuitive. What you wrote uses phrases such as "fake", which are far from intuitive.